# How to set specific start time in FlipClock js widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, momentjs, flipclock

I want to set New York time in `FlipClock.js` widget along with `moment.js`. I have tried with

```
HTML
<div class="my_flip_clock"></div>

JS
var a = moment.tz('America/New_York');
var clock = $('.my_flip_clock').FlipClock({
    clockFace: 'TwelveHourClock'
});
clock.setTime(new Date(a.format()).getTime() / 1000);
```

Comment: Could you provide a link to the moment.js and flipclock.js you are using?  Googling for the most likely ones doesn't have a moment.js with a tz method or a flipclock.js with a setTime method.

Comment: Hi @TonyMiller, here is the link for moment.js with tz method - [here](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) and setTime method [here](http://flipclockjs.com/api).

Answer (score 2):

From the [Moment Timezone documentation](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/):

There are two interfaces for using time zones with Moment.js.

moment.tz(..., String) is used to create a moment with a time zone, and moment().tz(String) is used to change the time zone on an existing moment.

```
var d = new Date(); // Get a new JS Date instance at current time in system time zone
var a = moment.tz(d.getTime(), 'America/New_York');  // Convert to New York time zone
var dny = new Date(a.format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss a')); // Get new JS Date instance for values in New York
var clock = $('.my_flip_clock').FlipClock(dny, {
    clockFace: 'TwelveHourClock'
});
```